# Trying to map postgres data into my desire format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have datas such as these:

```
Model Account

# created_at | sales | profit 

[#<Account:0x007fcf3657dd90
  id: 1,
  balance: 500,
  profit: nil,
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 02:27:43 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 02:27:43 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Account:0x007fcf3657dbb0
  id: 2,
  balance: 600,
  profit: 100,
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 14 Nov 2015 15:05:07 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 15:05:07 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Account:0x007fcf3657d9d0
  id: 3,
  balance: 1000,
  profit: 200,
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 14 Nov 2015 15:07:04 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 15:07:04 UTC +00:00>]
```

Desire format:

```
[{ period: 15 Nov 2015,
   balance: 600,
   profit: 100
  }, 
 { period: '14 Nov 2015',
   balance: 1000,
   profit: 200
 }]
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
def total_group_by_week
 total_profit = Account.group("DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at)").sum(:profit)
 chart = total_profit.map do |k, v|
  {period: k, balance: ?, profit: v}
end
chart
end
```

My problems are:

1. I am able to get total profits, and the date. But I don't know how to get ending balance for that day?
2. For example I want to get weekly data into that hash format, how can I limit 'period' of the hash value to only the past 7 days?